# How do I make a Global Variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global

So I would like for dashboard to be able to be modified inside one function, then be displayed in another function. Kind of like a public variable in java. Is this possible? See my code below.

```
var dashboard = new Array();
function init() {
    getXML(); //1.  goto get XML 2.// XML Parser
    displayXML();
}

function getXML() {
    console.log("getXML REACHED");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "file:///H:/ModelDisplayV1/ModelDisplayV1/files/dashboard.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
}

function xmlParser(xml) {
    dashboard[0] = 7;
    console.log(dashboard);
});
}

function displayXML() {
    console.log("display xml function reached!!!");
    console.log(dashboard);
}
```

When I finally try and get the `console.log(dashboard)` it says `dashboard is undefined`. I thought by declaring dashboard outside of my functions it would be global. How do I make it so I can alter the contents of dashboard in one function and retrieve them in another function?

I am more familiar with Java as opposed to Javascript.

Comment: In fixing your indentation, I noticed that there's an extra close paren and close brace after `xmlParser`.  Is that really what your code contains?  If so, you should fix your syntax errors and retest.

Comment: No it isnt. I had trouble copying code here and make it appear in the code block. The 4 spaces thing was weird it made some lines in the block and some not. So I basically just re-wrote a very simple version of what I was trying to do.

is there a way to just do something like <code></code> where you put the code in the middle and it formats it? the 4 spaces before each line seemed tedious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ajax call is asynchrous, so the displayXML() function is called in the init() method before dashboard is actually filled. So do this instead:

```
var dashboard = new Array();
function init() {
    getXML(); //1.  goto get XML 2.// XML Parser
}

function getXML() {
    console.log("getXML REACHED");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "file:///H:/ModelDisplayV1/ModelDisplayV1/files/dashboard.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
}

function xmlParser(xml) {
    dashboard[0] = 7;
    console.log(dashboard);
    displayXML();
});
}

function displayXML() {
    console.log("display xml function reached!!!");
    console.log(dashboard);
}
```

Comment: thankyou for the help! This worked great. Is there a way to to combat the asynchronous aspect of javascript? For example possibly using $(Document.OnReady) in order to call functions in the order i want them to be called from one init method but make sure they wait for the one before them to finish?

Comment: You can make an ajax request synchronous like this:  $.ajax({... your stuff..., async: false}); Try to avoid this though, because this will cause your browser to stop responding while the file is being fetched. More here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

There's only two kinds of scopes in javascript - global and function. If it's not declared inside a function, it's global. If it's not declared using var, it's also implicitly global.

Answer (score 1):

The `var` keyword declares a variable as local, otherwise you can omit it and it will make it global.

The other option is to insert it into the window object like so:

```
window.dashboard = new Array();
```

This is the preferred method for insert variables into the global scope.

Also blah blah blah about not abusing global variables that you probably know.

Answer (score 1):

if you want Java-like class semantics in javascript look at using the Revealing Module pattern.

http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Getting in the habit of correctly organizing your javascript code from the beginning will save you many headaches.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `context` to `$.ajax()`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "file:///H:/ModelDisplayV1/ModelDisplayV1/files/dashboard.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    context: this,
    success: xmlParser 
});
```